# Amazon EC2 Connects to RDS from command line but not from web server

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, mysqli, amazon-ec2

If have an amazon ec2 instance running php 5.5 and apache2.  I am connecting to my RDS database using a simple test.php script.  When I run the script as ec2-user or as root I am able to get a connection.
When I run the same script via my webserver I get

> Connection Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip' (13).

I've tried the public and private IP addresses.  This script does work from my other, non-amazon, webservers running the same php and apache.  Not sure what to look at next since it works on the command line.  Here's the example of the test.php script, pretty straight forward.

```
define("DB_IP”,”ip”);
define("DB_USERNAME”,”username”);
define("DB_PASSWORD”,”password”);
define("DB_DATABASE”,”database”);

echo "Connecting...\n";
$conn = new mysqli(DB_IP, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE, 3306);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die(date('H:i:s')." Connection " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo date('H:i:s')." Connected successfully\n";
```

Why would the connection work on the command line but not work when called from the web server?

Comment: Check your security group's inbound and outbound setting.

Comment: Thanks zairwolf...It is able to connect from the command line using the test.php script. Would php being called from the apache web server use different network permissions?

Comment: How do you run it from command line?

Comment: Php test.php. I can do this from both my ec2-user and as super user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you running on your EC2?
Just asking in case it's an SELinux (Security-Enhanced Linux), in which case it could possibly be the security limitation.

At your terminal, if you run:

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

you should be able to see this limitation (whether your webserver can "network" or not. If it cannot, then run this, which should fix your problem:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Hope that solves it, otherwise I don't see where the issue can arise, especially since you say you can connect via terminal (so AWS security groups should not be the issue).

Keep us posted ;)

Comment: FYI, this solved the problem for me as well, the reason I am posting is to let people know that most basic CentOS 7 AMIs by default has SELinux settings set to this. Was frustrating to say the least.

Comment: 2022 and this answer is still rocking. Thank-you.